# Getting attachment thu REST AP

Tags: apex, rest-api, apexrest

Kindly help me in resolving the issue.
I am not able to parse the response from the json data.
I need to get the **Body** part of the attachment.
It's giving the error 'Required field missing' a.Body.
I am getting the reponse from server thru hRes.getBody(),which is fine.
Apex :-

```
    Http h2 = new Http();
   final PageReference urlPg= new PageReference('https://xxxxxx-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/query/');
         urlPg.getParameters().put('q','Select Body,ParentId from Attachment where ParentId=\'0017F000003o4gJ\''); 
           String uri  = urlPg.getUrl();

        HttpRequest req2= new HttpRequest();
           req2.setEndpoint(uri);
           req2.setMethod('GET');
           req2.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + newaccessToken);

        HttpResponse hRes = h2.send(req2);
    system.debug('1111 '+hRes.getBody());       
showreshttp =hRes.getBody();

            JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(hRes.getBody());
            while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
                if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME)){
                    String fieldName = parser.getText();
                    parser.nextToken();
                    if(fieldName == 'Body') {
                    string    data= parser.getText();
                    }
                }
              }

                    Attachment a= new Attachment();
                     a.Name='xyz';
                     a.Body=  EncodingUtil.base64Decode(data);
                     a.ParentId='0010I00001odnie';
                      insert a;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REST API doesn't return the Body (a Blob field) directly back through the API for performance reasons. Instead, you need to call the [Blob Retrieve](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_blob_retrieve.htm) endpoint from the value derived from Body, which will look something like `/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Attachment/OOPXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Body`. The reason why you're getting the error is because the body couldn't be decoded, because it's not a base64 string, just a normal URL fragment.

For your body, you'll need to do something like this:

```
HttpRequest bodyRequest = new HttpRequest();
bodyRequest.setEndpoint(new Url(new url(urlPg.getUrl()), data).toExternalForm());
bodyRequest.setMethod('GET');
bodyRequest.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth '+newAccessToken);
HttpResponse bodyResponse = new http().send(bodyRequest);
                Attachment a= new Attachment();
                 a.Name='xyz.png';
                a.Body=bodyResponse.getBodyAsBlob();//bodyResponse.getBody()
                 a.ParentId='001xxxx0001odnie';
                  insert a;
```

Comment: thnx a lot ......i tried this earlier. In that case what should i use in a.Body?

Comment: is a.body=hRes.getBody() correct?

Comment: @vineet No, you have to make another callout.

Comment: See i tried like this a.Body=Blob.ValueOf(hRes.getBody()); Some garbge value is getting saved in attachments now,but not the exact image file. Neways will make another callout to check. Btw, the URL in another callout ,I have to use yours' or mine url.

Comment: currently i used ur url.

Comment: @vineet My code should be compatible with yours verbatim.

Comment: i think we are pretty much close. its an image file ...do we have to add something like "content type',xyz.png. I am saying this because  again something is coming but not the exact file...i just tried ur code.

Comment: @sfdcfox...yeah its coming but not the image files. Can't say why. i tries with text files .Neways thnx.

Comment: @vineet You need to use getBodyAsBlob. That should fix the problem you're seeing.

Comment: correct thnx a lot. That certainly sresolved the issue.